# chart js date range picker apply function

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Jquery - Bootstrap Daterangepicker Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
</head>
<body>


<input type="text" class="daterange" />


<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.daterange').daterangepicker();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I want to apply a function to my chart to change the date label below is my script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3R9S.png)

Comment: What is the script you used to add date range picker?

Answer (score -1):

I got a partial answer now I have to connect this date to my DB PostgreSQL

```
<script>
    $('.daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function add1(){
        let ab=[{% for item in values2 %}
            {{item}},
        {% endfor %}]
    mixedChart.data.datasets[2].data=ab;
         mixedChart.update();
           });
 </script>
```

I want to change the above code to start and end dates when I click on the start date or end date it should change dynamically at my backend if any suggestions or clues let me know plz same for the end date